# What to do with questions about the UK's referendum results?

Tags: discussion

Since the UK's EU referendum has been in favour of Leave, there might be a few questions in the upcoming weeks that will ask around what will happen. I've already closed one of them as a duplicate of [EEA Family permit and UK referendum](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8455/eea-family-permit-and-uk-referendum/8470#8470) but I'm not sure if that's the sensible solution here, as in the future (which might be 1-2-3 years later) there might be actually an answer for all of these questions

Comment: Its a good idea tbh. Can we do something like this for Canadian Express Entry program too? I have been thinking of this for a while now since users come and end up asking the same question over and over again.

Comment: @DipenShah I think http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4451/query-on-ielts-score-for-express-entry-visa-canada is the dup target for the express entry questions

Comment: Agreed. However that questions focuses on ielts only. There are lots of other factors affecting an express entry profile which needs to be mentioned somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Modified my answer to a community wiki on [The UK has voted to leave the EU. How does this affect UK/EU (and other) citizens living/working in the UK and vice-versa?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8593/the-uk-has-voted-to-leave-the-eu-how-does-this-affect-eu-nationals-living-worki/8594#8594)

Feel free to edit it to add more up to date information as we know more, and use it as a duplicate target for subsequent questions.

In the duplicate target I've been adding the [brexit](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brexit) tag, along with a comment that the question might be reopened once more information is known about the specific question. For me this sounds a sensible idea for the moment.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a few friends ask me about what can be done under the existing rules, while they wait (a potentially long time) for news of what might become. As I think that's a different question, and also one that's answerable today, I've gone ahead an asked it as a new question.

My question [is a little broad](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8630/eu-citizens-living-and-working-in-the-uk-and-current-pre-existing-rules-for-p), but hopefully can help people see what's available today, as well as acting as a duplicate target for some other brexit-related queries...